# Having a hard time using CSS selector with beautifulsoup on flickr, am i doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

Yes I know I should type in the code but I could not find it in the page source formatted therefore I just copied a picture of the relevant code: [Trying to select overlay (Click this pick)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNwOb.png)

So what I am trying to do is target the overlay `div`, and copy the link. I am using pythons requests and bs4 (beautifulSoup) module.

```
# Get the web page
res = requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/search/?=&text=new+york')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
soupElement = soup.select('div.overlay')
```

Yet the `soupElement` returns empty. What am I doing wrong here? Is the `div` not selectable or.

Comment: If you inspect the page you will see that the data is loaded in javascript using YUI. Even though your select is not correct as stated in the answer below, it does not matter because what you are looking for does not exist in the returned data because it has not been loaded on the page yet.

Comment: @martinB0103 oh okay thanks. And what would be the right select statement?

Comment: it should be as the answer below shows it, but it does not matter because what you are trying to select does not exist on the page. You would need to use something like Selenium to run the javascript and load the data to the page

Answer (score 2):

Well based on your picture, `overlay` is an `<a>` tag so `'div.overlay'` should be `'a.overlay'`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I wrote it too fast but yeah I've tried and that does not work either. I think @MartinB103 is right